# How to get user's authorization credentials in code with spring security?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, crud

What I'm trying to do is to build CRUD REST service. It will maintain a database of users and theirs records. I'd like to allow users to get access only to their own records. 
I use Spring Security for authentication and store user's password hashed with Bcrypt. All I can understand right now that my spring-security.xml shuld like:

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:http-basic />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username =?" />
    </authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

But for farther work of the service I need to know exactly which user have been authorized. So how could I do that? And for related matter is there way to get around mainlining user's role in the database since there's no more roles planned.

Comment: You can use the Authentication object in the session

Comment: or use [Method Security Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simple.

```java
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String username = auth.getName();
Object credentials = auth.getCredentials();
```

To access the *credentials*, i.e. the password, you need to set `erase-credentials` to `false`:

```xml
<security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">
  ...
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Or if configured via annotations then:

```java
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.eraseCredentials(false);
    /* configure user-service, password-encoder etc ... */
}
```

Comment: @Jason The file with the Spring Security config.

Comment: My confusion came because I'm using Grails, not Spring Framework. Grails is built on top of Spring Framework and uses Spring Security. The erase credentials goes in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` and is not XML; the line reads `grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerManager.eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication = false`

Comment: I do the above thing but still receive credentials  as empty , any advise?

Comment: I figured out the auth.getCredentials() part on my own. In my configuration method, I've specified           httpSecurity.antMatchers("/admin/*").hasRole(UserDto.RoleEnum.ADMIN.toString())
But I don't see where in the code it enforces this. I suspect I need to do some further configuration, but I'm not sure where.