# How to extract login user information through spring security?

Tags: spring-security

Hello i am new to spring security. I want get login user information through.

I am using

```
users = (Users)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Is it correct?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're using one of several ways to to retrieve the currently authenticated principal. You're making a static call to the `SecurityContextHolder`. Precisely `String currentPrincipalName = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get user's authorization credentials in code with spring security?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412138/how-to-get-users-authorization-credentials-in-code-with-spring-security/30414548)